# Is Null criteria in update query is not working

Tags: ms-access

This query will return a value (albeit not what I want) when I remove the Is Null criteria. When the Is Null criteria is included, nothing is returned. The T_4006_Infusion.ProductID column does have a null cell that is a number data type within MS Access. This should be working right? Any ideas please?

```
UPDATE T_4006_Infusion
INNER JOIN T_Temp_MaxProductID ON T_4006_Infusion.ProductID = T_Temp_MaxProductID.MaxProductID  
SET T_4006_Infusion.ProductID = [T_Temp_MaxProductID].[MaxProductID]+1
WHERE (((T_4006_Infusion.ProductID) Is Null));
```

Comment: Update statements don't "return" anything. What do you mean by "nothing is returned"?

Comment: @Bohemian In Access, you can preview what the values will be as part of the update query. Also, the warning says you are about to update 0 rows.

Comment: The INNER JOIN should only return records where Product fields have data and match. Can't join on Null because Null does not equal anything, not even another Null. Therefore, when you add that filter criteria, there are no records to update. Perhaps need LEFT JOIN with that WHERE. Every record that is then retrieved will get the same value.

Comment: @June7 Ah thank you for the explanation on INNER JOIN! That makes sense. Unfortunately, changing the inner join to left join doesn't seem to solve the issue. I might just abandon this route and try to find another way to fill this empty field with a value that is 1 greater than the max of the column.

Comment: What happened? Could use DMax() or DLookup() or VBA.

Comment: @June7 The Left Join now returns the cell with a null value, which seems like an improvement. But it's not updating that empty/null cell to [MaxProductID]+1. The warning says 1 row is about to be updated, but I don't see any changes to the table after running.

Comment: Oh, of course, MaxProductID is not in the resulting dataset. You are trying to update same field used in JOIN. Unusual. Use domain aggregate.

Comment: @June7, thanks! I was able to solve it using DMax() within the SET line. If you leave a comment, I'll give you credit for the answer. I posted my code below as well.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it. With advice from @June7, I removed all uses of MaxProductID and just used DMax(). Much simpler.

```
UPDATE T_4006_Infusion   
SET T_4006_Infusion.ProductID = DMax("ProductID","T_4006_Infusion","")+1 
WHERE (((T_4006_Infusion.ProductID) Is Null));
```

I've combined this with an append query that adds a record but with the ProductID field blank. Then I run this update query as part of a larger macro.